# Syntax error when calling function inside if statement in trigger function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to create a trigger function that simply calls a function within an if statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."onTrack"()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        "updateUserStats"(NEW."userId");
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        "updateUserStats"(OLD."userId");
    END IF

    RETURN NULL
END
$BODY$;
```

However, when I try to create the function, I get this error

[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, as according to the docs, this syntax is correct. Removing the quotes around the functions will not work as the name is case sensitive and also is still a syntax error.

I am on version "PostgreSQL 9.5.14"

Comment: `perform updateUserStats(NEW.userId);` ?

Comment: also you missed semicolons after `END IF` and `RETURN NULL`

Comment: Oh, that seemed to work. Make it an answer? Can't believe I missed this when reading the docs.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really avoid quoted identifiers (`"onTrack"`, `"userId"`, ...) they are much more trouble than they are worth it.

Comment: They are named that way for consistency. I've not really had any trouble with them at all, it's down to preference imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `perform` keyword:

```
IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
    PERFORM "updateUserStats"(NEW."userId");
ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
    PERFORM "updateUserStats"(OLD."userId");
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call that function:

```
...
perform updateUserStats(NEW.userId);
...
```

also you missed semicolons after `END IF` and `RETURN NULL`